# Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3 is not compatible with net462

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

I am trying to use **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** package in my application which is targeting .NET framework 4.6.2, the application is deployed in service fabric(SDK - 4.2.477 & Runtime -7.2.477).

I am getting below error while building the application

*Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0).*
*One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.*

*Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win7-x64. Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)*
*One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win7-x64).*

**Note :** I have installed all the dependent packages of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Am i missing anything here?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using when you install the NuGet package? Or if you're doing it from the command line, what version of nuget.exe? And is there some reason you're unwilling to use [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus)? Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is essentially deprecated.

Comment: The package [depends](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/456659791af354496e95c7fb88067f2ee19d982a/eng/Directory.Build.Common.props#L113 ) on .NET Framework 4.6.1, should work with 4.6.2.

Comment: I am using VS2017. I have not checked on Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. Let me check that

Answer (score 1):

.Net Framework compatible for [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/5.1.3) is  **.NETStandard 2.0**
Try to update your .Net framework to 2.0 version.
[image]